# How can I define the a stored procedure that return values in mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I want to define a function as stored procedure in MySQL.

I tried a procedure as follows:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE getGroupUsers(IN groupId int) return curser

BEGIN
 Declare services_curs cursor for SELECT `service_id`,`service_name`,`service_type_value`,`service_label`,`parent`,`service_group` from services;

open services_curs;

return services_curs;

END //

DELIMITER ;
```

but an error occurs:

```
#1313 - RETURN is only allowed in a FUNCTION
```

I know that this is a terrible syntax error. What is the correct syntax?

Comment: Have you considered using a function? Functions return things as the error suggests.

Answer (score 2):

On procedures you can use `OUT` variables, which get filled and are available outside the procedure. As said above, a MySQL procedure does not return a value. You'll need a `stored function` achieve that.

A little example on how to use an `OUT` variable can be found [in the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html).

Answer (score 0):

Use `select` in procedure for returing value otherwise use `function` which `returns` values.